# How can I create and update a subcollection using Angular and Clound Firestore?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular8

I have created a Collection "Ticket" in Firestore. I want to when I update data will add action in subcollection 'action' but noe have a data like a picture field 'actionSentence' data not entered

app.ts

```
  isSubmitAssignDev() {
    if (this.editTicket.controls.assign.value) {
      this.ticketService.setActionById(this.id, this.editTicket.controls.status.value, this.editTicket.controls.assign.value)
    }
  }
  setActionSentence() {
    if (this.status.value === 'Accepted') {
      this.editTicket.patchValue({
        actionSentence: 'MA accepted ticket'
    })
    } else if (this.status.value === 'Rejected') {
      this.editTicket.patchValue({
        actionSentence: 'MA rejected ticket'
      })
    } else if (this.status.value === 'Pending') {
      this.editTicket.patchValue({
        actionSentence: 'MA set pending'
      })
    } else if (this.status.value === 'Assigned') {
      this.editTicket.patchValue({
        actionSentence: 'Supervidor assigned ticket'
      })
    } else if (this.status.value === 'Resolved') {
      this.editTicket.patchValue({
        actionSentence: 'Dev resoled task'
      })
    }
  }
```

app.service.ts

```
  setActionById(id: any, status: any, staff: any, actionSEntence: any) {
    this.afs.collection('ticket').doc(id)
      .collection('action')
      .add({
        actionSEntence,
        staff,
        status,
        date: new Date(),
      })
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `actionSEntence` is not being added to the document because there is no value in it, and Firestore will not add a field with a Null value. You can see that by checking this line in your code:

```
this.ticketService.setActionById(this.id, this.editTicket.controls.status.value, this.editTicket.controls.assign.value)
```

Where you are using 3 parameters, intead of 4, so since `setActionById`'s last paramenter is `actionSEntence: any`, it assumes it as a null value, which  `this.afs...add({});` will simply ignore.

So in order to fix it you will just need to set the 4th value when calling `this.ticketService.setActionById()`.